# Set different hyperlink for each data in the gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, hyperlink

I am try to add hyperlinks to the `stockName` in the `gridview` from the database. I manage to make the hyperlink to direct to a single page only. How can i add different url hyperlink for different stockname?

The url i wanna to add for the 1st stockname is `gentingdisplay.aspx`, 2nd is `pangkordisplay.aspx`, 3rd is `langkawidisplay.aspx` and so on.

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView2" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
        CellPadding="4" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource2" ForeColor="#333333" 
        GridLines="None">
        <RowStyle BackColor="#F7F6F3" ForeColor="#333333" />
        <Columns>
             <asp:BoundField DataField="StockID" HeaderText="Stock ID" 
                SortExpression="StockID" />
                <asp:HyperLinkField 
  DataNavigateUrlFields="StockName" 
  DataNavigateUrlFormatString="gentingdisplay.aspx?StockID=0" 
  HeaderText="Stock Name" 
  SortExpression="StockName" 
  DataTextField="StockName" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="StockPrice" HeaderText="Stock Price" 
                SortExpression="StockPrice" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="UnitAvailable" HeaderText="Unit Available" 
                SortExpression="UnitAvailable" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the documentation for [DataNavigateUrlFields](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.hyperlinkfield.datanavigateurlfields(v=vs.110).aspx) says, you can provide a comma-separated list of fields to use in the [DataNavigateUrlFormatString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.hyperlinkfield.datanavigateurlformatstring(v=vs.110).aspx).

So if I understand you correctly and you want the `StockName` to make up part of the hyperlink path and pass the `StockID` in the StockID querystring, you can use this in your `HyperLinkField`:

```
<asp:HyperLinkField 
  DataNavigateUrlFields="StockName,StockID" 
  DataNavigateUrlFormatString="{0}display.aspx?StockID={1}" 
  HeaderText="Stock Name" 
  SortExpression="StockName" 
  DataTextField="StockName" />
```

Here `{0}` maps to `StockName` and `{1}` maps to `StockID`, using the standard [`String.Format`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format.aspx) syntax.

Comment: erm, i actually want the stockName to act as a hyperlink to link to  other pages that i have made, and in order to identify which hyperlink to connect to which stockName, stockID is used to identify the hyperlinks. is this possible?

Comment: ya, gentingm pangkor are the value that will be shown in the StockName

Comment: ok, so for the first row with e.g. StockName=genting and StockID=10, the hyperlink should point to `gentingdisplay.aspx?StockID=10`, the second row `pangkordisplay.aspx?StockID=27` and so on

Comment: ya, thats what i wanna know... so how should i write the code for getting the hyperlink to bind with the stockname or stockid?

Answer (score 0):

You probably want

```
  <asp:HyperLinkField DataNavigateUrlFields="StockName" 
  DataNavigateUrlFormatString="{0}display.aspx" 
  HeaderText="Link" 
  SortExpression="StockName" 
  DataTextField="StockName" />
```

However, I think it may bad practice to organize your site with the pages designed in this manner - It may be hard to maintain.

Comment: is it possible to make my data in the gridview to link with different hyperlink?